# C# DTLS implementation (server / client)

Tags: c#, security, udp, bouncycastle, dtls

I am trying to get dtls working in c#. I discovered that there is a bouncycastle c# implementation, however, there does not appear to be any documentation or samples on how to use it.

I looked at the test app in the source control, but I don't see where and how you specify the port that the server can listen on.

Does anyone have some working samples showing how you can setup a server to listen on a specific port?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can see [IOTBroker.cloud c# client](https://github.com/mobius-software-ltd/iotbroker.cloud-windows-client)

It has non blocking DTLS client implementation. 
For example please check UDPClient in CoAP or MQTT-SN

[Mobius Software](https://www.mobius-software.com)

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's been near impossible finding information on DTLS for c#....